# XSD Schema: Make element *List optional

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, schema, elementtree

Really need your help with some XML configuration. I have a schema like:

```
<Root ...>
.
.
<xs:complexType name="GlobalDataType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Other1ELement" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element name="MyELementList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="MyELement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
             <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Element1" type="T_Custom" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <xs:element name="Element2" type="T_Custom" minOccurs="0"/>   
                </xs:sequence>
             </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Element1Visible" type="xs:boolean" default="true" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="Element2Visible" type="xs:boolean" default="true" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Other2ELement" minOccurs="0">
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
.
.
```

for me everything  works fine except line with: `name="MyELementList" minOccurs="0"`
my validator throw an error that this List should be in provided .xml file like `<MyELementList/>` and no matter that I set `minOccurs="0"` for this element. For nested elements everything  works correct.

Comment: You've posted an XSD snipped out of context.  Is `MyElementList` the root element?  Please [edit] your post and include a minimal but complete XSD and sample XML that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A complex type defines a content model, and that's where you say whether a particular element is optional. Optionality is a property of where the element is used, not a property of the element itself. So minOccurs is only relevant on an element declared within a complex type - technically it's a property of the element particle, not of the element declaration.

Comment: Thx! I added some more levels of my element, could you please look on it once more. My MyELementList is a part of complex type as well. To say true does it mean that I can't to make it optional in such structure? MyELementList  is stored inside the complex type GlobalDataType

Comment: @Reni21: You've still not added a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.  Until you do that, we can only guess that you have a conceptual misunderstanding (as Michael Kay has done here), or that there's another occurrence of `MyElementList` use for which `minOccurs="0"` is not specified, or that the error is coming not from an actual XSD processor but from another XML application, etc.   Make a real [mcve] if you want further help.  Making us guess is unproductive.